# Sync favorite tabs between SO and SE

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I always find it confusing when navigating my favorites, because of tab names are quite alike:

`added views newest activity votes`

Here's how it goes:

1. Added means ones I have added recently, okay.
2. Views - ones that are most popular on SO, okay.
3. Newest - erm.. newest asked?
4. Activity - ones with recent changes, okay
5. Votes - okay.

Now let's change to SE favorites:

`votes recent newest added`

1. Votes - okay
2. Recent, hmm.. where does that came from, are those recently added? Hint says "sort by recent activity", now that is better.
3. Newest, okay.
4. Added, okay.

Now the feature request is either to sync those tabs choice across SE/SO, change the order to be the same, or at least make their names and hints identical.